# send JSON string from android to RESTful web service

Tags: java, android, json, netbeans

I'm trying to create a simple sign in/login form in my android app using JSON string and Restful web service.
the login is working if I put the JSON data in the NetBeans IDE side manually, but don't know how to send back the data with the new username and password to the web service in order to create a new user.

my AsyncTask that using the JSON array:

```
    private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);// as a json string : [{},{},{},{}]
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

            // ---check user name and password---

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                if (obj.getString("User Name").equals(user.getUserName())
                        && obj.getString("Password").equals(
                                user.getPassword())) {
                    userNameAndPasswordCorrect = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (userNameAndPasswordCorrect) {
                changeActivity(MenuScreen.class);
                userNameAndPasswordCorrect = false;
            } else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(WelcomeScreen.this)
                        .setTitle("Wrong Details")
                        .setMessage(
                                "One or more of your details is incorrect\nPlease try again")
                        .setPositiveButton("O.K",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                    }
                                }).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The readJSONFeed:

```
public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {

    Log.d("JSON", "readJSONFeed");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

    try {

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON", "Failed to download file");
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

The NetBeans IDE code:

```
@Path("generic")
public class GenericResource {

@Context
private UriInfo context;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of GenericResource
 */
public GenericResource() {
}

/**
 * Retrieves representation of an instance of com.it.as.GenericResource
 * @return an instance of java.lang.String
 */
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String getJson() {
JsonArrayBuilder value = Json.createArrayBuilder();
JsonObject jo1 = Json.createObjectBuilder()
.add("User Name", "aaa")
.add("Password", "12345").build();
value.add(jo1);

JsonObject jo2 = Json.createObjectBuilder()
.add("User Name", "bbb")
.add("Password", "98765").build();
value.add(jo2);
return value.build().toString();
}
/**
 * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of GenericResource
 * @param content representation for the resource
 * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
 */
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public void putJson(String content) {
}
}
```

Thanks,
Amit.

Comment: This will give you an idea on how to achieve it. http://codex2android.blogspot.in/2015/11/writing-data-back-to-json.html , But I have used AsynhttpClient loopj library instead of httpclient